# Position children from the center of their parent

Tags: html, css, position

I have a child element in a parent container. I would like the child to be positioned from the center of the container, not from its top left corner. Here is a basic schema:

```
                                       x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
.parent                                x                                   x
{                                      x                                   x
    position: absolute;                x                                   x
}                                      x                                   x
                                       x                                   x
.child                                 x                 .                 x
{                                      x                 |                 x
    position: absolute;                x       top: 50px |                 x
    top: 50px;                         x                 v----->x x x      x
    left: 50px;                        x            left: 50px  x   x      x
}                                      x                        x x x      x
                                       x                                   x
                                       x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
```

How can I achieve this in pure css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't officially change the reference point of the positioning, but you *can* position at that centre point and then use `margin`s to approximate your intent:

```
.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

[Simple JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lxxt6/1/).

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility in CSS to change the reference point from top or the bottom and left or right to another position. This is how CSS works.

The only possibility here is to work with additional `margin`, e.g.:

```
.child {
    left: 50%;
    margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, you could also do this with transforms:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #ffa;
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #e7e7e7;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(50px, 50px);
    transform: translate(50px, 50px);
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    background-color: #000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```